# how to disable using Jcenter repositosy by sonarsource plugin

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, jcenter, jfrog-container-registry

I'am using sonar preview mode in maven project, but when dependencies are downloaded , sonarsource use JFrog Jcenter repository as a mirror of our central repositories, but it doesn't contain all dependencies

logs:

[DEBUG] Using mirror x-maven-central (https://company-url.com/jcenter/) for central (https://company-url.com/x-mvn-delivered).

then I have a warnning:
[WARNING] The POM for com.x.x.http:com.x.as.keycloak.jaxrs.adapter:jar:4.0.6 is missing, no dependency information available

then I got errors for missing dependencies like:

*Could not find artifact x.x.x.as.keycloak.jaxrs.adapter:jar:4.0.6 in maven-central (https://company-url.com/jcenter/)*

is there a way to disable using this mirror?

Answer (score 2):

Check your maven settings.xml for what mirrors or repos you have.

Normally this file can be found at ~/.m2/settings.xml

or if you download / unzip maven it would be something like:

apache-maven-3.5.0/conf/settings.xml

You can also try to run the dependency resolve on the command line manually:

mvn dependency:resolve